# Issue with including variable in SQL statement - in Python 3.4

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, python-3.4

I am attempting to calculate the distance between pairs of coordinates and update a table column with the results.

The calculation of the distance between each pair of coordinates is working fine when I print the results from the loop (see screenshot) .

However there is an issue with the distance added to the table (see screenshot)- all the rows have the distance of 15886, the distance between the points (-36.8090839, 174.718904)  and (0,0).

It appears I have an issue with how my UPDATE Command is being constructed- specifically the adding of the variable for the coordinates (lat and long) sourced from the table .

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

I'm new to python.

[image]

```
import _sqlite3,  time,  datetime, gpxpy.geo
conn = _sqlite3.connect('SpatialDB')
c = conn.cursor()

lat1 = -36.8090839
lon1 = 174.718904

c.execute('Select * FROM Media')
data = c.fetchall()
for row in data:
    lat2 = row[1]
    lon2 = row[2]
    dist = gpxpy.geo.haversine_distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)/1000
    SQLCommand =("UPDATE Media SET LastQueried = Current_Timestamp, Distance  = ?");
    value =  [dist]
    c.execute(SQLCommand, value)
    print(dist)

conn.commit()
c.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Without a WHERE clause, UPDATE will set all rows to the same value.  See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Update_%28SQL%29) (very end of the article).

Comment: Also, `conn.commit()` may need to be inside loop, else only last `c.execute()` is committed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`distance` value is different for each row in the `for` loop. Because the `update` statement is in the `for` loop, each time the `distance` column (for all rows) gets updated to the current row's value as there is no `where` clause to specify which row to `update`. Hence you see the same value in the `distance` column (the last value of distance from the for loop).

Assuming `business` is unique for each row, use it as a `where` clause so the corresponding row gets updated.

```
import _sqlite3,  time,  datetime, gpxpy.geo
conn = _sqlite3.connect('SpatialDB')
c = conn.cursor()

lat1 = -36.8090839
lon1 = 174.718904

c.execute('Select * FROM Media')
data = c.fetchall()
for row in data:
    lat2 = row[1]
    lon2 = row[2]
    busns= row[0]
    dist = gpxpy.geo.haversine_distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2)/1000
    c.execute("UPDATE Media SET LastQueried = ?, Distance  = ? WHERE Business = ?",(Current_Timestamp,dist,busns))

conn.commit()
c.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense- but now I get  the following error                 "Operational Error unhandled by user code"  ..near "(":syntax error.  Searching on this error it appears there can be a range of causes (casts, syntax issues...etc.) none of which I can immediately  see in the suggested code.

Comment: This time "NameError was unhandled by user code..name 'latitude' is not defined"